# How to get value of json array in jquery after ajax respond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've received data fro Json as below But I don't understand much about Json object and Json array. I've always confused with it. another hand I would like to ask expert here. How can I passing data from this json data to any div after ajax respond

**Issue** can't passing data to html element from this json

### Here is my json data

```
{
    "res": {
        "nav": [
            {"text":"SERVICES"},
            {"text":"CooSurf"},
            {"text":"CooMartsdf"},
            {"text":"Devices"}, 
            {"text":"asdf"},
            {"text":"Press Release"},
            {"text":"Speach"},
            {"text":"fqas"},
            {"text":"Network Coverages"},
            {"text":"CooSurf"},
            {"text":"CooMartsdf"},
            {"text":"Devices"},
            {"text":"test"}
        ],
        "content": [
            {"name":"Englishasdfasdf"},
            {"name":"kh_nameasdfasdf"}, 
            {"name":"asdfasdfasdf"}, 
            {"name":"sdfasdfasdf"}, 
            {"name":"English"}, 
            {"name":"English"}, 
            {"name":"FQAS"}, 
            {"name":"Network Coverages"}, 
            {"name":"kh_nameasdfasdf"}
        ], 
        "promot": [
            {"title":"Englishasffasdf"}, 
            {"title":"kh_namedfasdfasdf"}, 
            {"title":"English"}, 
            {"title":"English"}, 
            {"title":"English"}, 
            {"title":"asdfasdfas"}, 
            {"title":"asdfasdfasdf"}, 
            {"title":"asdfasdfasd"}
        ] 
    }
}
```

### Here is my ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: url,
                data: $("#searching_from").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    $(".loadings").css({'display': 'inline'});
                }, success: function (data) {
                   var json = data.res;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    console.log(obj );
                    $(".modal-body").append(data.res);
                    $(".loadings").css({'display': 'none'});
                }
            });
```

** This is function in Model **

```
public function search_data($keyword) {

        if ($this->msearch($keyword, 'text', 'nav') == TRUE) {

            $res['nav'] = $this->gsearch($keyword, 'text', 'text', 'nav');
        }if ($this->msearch($keyword, 'name', 'content') == TRUE) {

            $res['content'] = $this->gsearch($keyword, 'name', 'name', 'content');
        }
        if ($this->msearch($keyword, 'title', 'promot') == TRUE) {

            $res['promot'] = $this->gsearch($keyword, 'title', 'title', 'promot');
        } else {
            $res[] = false;
        }
        return json_encode(array('res' => $res));
    }

    public function msearch($keyword, $like_col, $table) {

        $this->db->like($like_col, $keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function gsearch($keyword, $like_col, $select, $table) {


        $this->db->select($select);
        $this->db->like($like_col, $keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your json data, which is an object, *data*. I assume you want to pass the list of names in your html element.
With jQuery do

```
$(yourElement).html(data.res.content.map(function(object){
    return object.name;
}).join(", "));
```

Hope this fits your needs.

**Updated**
I removed the use of JSON.parse above because jQuery automatically parse json into a js object.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Oh I've forgotten that jQuery already make this parsing en give you the JS object. So I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks I'm waiting you sire

Comment: I get TypeError: data.res is undefined